# Rails multiple select form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a multiple select form where a user can move IP addresses from the left select box to the right side (I'm not sure what that object is called).

I have my basic form code, but it's showing a dropdown instead (I've taken out the irrelevant code):

```
<%= form_for @network_host_groups do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :network_hosts, @network_hosts.collect { |n| [ n.ip_address, n.id ] } multiple: true, include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Which looks like:

[image]

However, I'm trying to get something like:

[image]

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [the docs for select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) you'll see it takes 2 sets of options: `options` - for Rails options, and `html_options` for additional attributes to include on the generated HTML `<select>` tag.

`include_blank` is a Rails option, whereas `multiple` is an HTML attribute so these need to be passed in separate hashes:

Also, it looks like when tidying your code to post the question you've lost a comma after the end of your `collect` block so be sure to make sure that's included when retrying this.

That's the reason why available hosts is appearing as a single item dropdown instead of a list anyway. Implementing the moving between "available" and "assigned" lists is beyond the scope of a single question.

Comment: Ok, have the presentation figured out, but what's the logic supposed to look like?  The left side can't actually contain the form element to pass on submit since only the objects in the right side should have the controller action performed.  Am I wrong?

Comment: That's right. Very briefly, it's likely that the left hand *Available* list will be generated using the `select_tag` helper i.e. it isn't bound to one of your model attributes using `f.select...` initially populated with the appropriate IP addresses.. and then the 2 arrows will need some JavaScript bound which moves items between the 2 lists.